# .htaccess redirect a dynamic page to an external page URL won't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect a few specific dynamic php pages to an external website domain. For example,

`siteA.com/home/space.php?uid=357&do=thread&id=396`

to

`siteB.com`

I put the following in my .htaccess but it didn't work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Redirect home/space.php?uid=357&do=thread&id=396 http://www.siteB.com
```

what's wrong with this? any suggestion is appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this:

```
Redirect home/space.php?uid=357&do=thread&id=396 http://www.siteB.com
```

to this:

```
RewriteRule ^[home/space.php?uid=357&do=thread&id=396]+$ http://www.siteB.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RewriteCond` for matching query string:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uid=357&do=thread&id=396$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/space\.php$ http://www.siteB.com [L,NC,R=302]
```